# Distributing tasks that can't be programmatically defined with Celery and Rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq, celery

We would like to use Celery and RabbitMq to distribute large document annotation task. In our setting, workers are users connected to an annotation web application. They are asked to add manual annotation on the document that the application shows them. Each time a new user is connected to the application a new worker is available and task can be assign to him.
Is Celery and/or RabbitMQ are suitable for this use case ?

Answer (score 1):

> Is Celery and/or RabbitMQ are suitable for this use case ?

I'd say no.

Celery / RabbitMQ are better suited to automated processes. It can be used for stuff that requires manual (human) action, but I don't think it's a good choice in your case.

I think you would be better off with a database to store a list of tasks for a given user, and to show that list of tasks to the user when they log in to the app.